# Parse dynamic formula in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have certain mathematical formulas to fetch records from database. Those formulas are Hard coded in the Function/SP. I need to move all my formulas to a separate table, i will be calling the Formula ID from my Function/SP so that the formula needs to be substituted with the values at run time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And where's your question ? Any problematic code to share ?

Comment: How can i do this? that the question!!

Comment: I need to move this formula to table. @ run time i will fetch that formula and run. Question is how I have column names as part of this formula, how do i substitute those formula with the column names?

Comment: Try dynamic sql using [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130)

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
DECLARE
    formula VARCHAR2(100) := '3 * 4 + 1';
    r NUMBER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :res := '||formula||'; END;' USING OUT r;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'r = ' || r );
END;

r = 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Tom Kyte's answers on the evaluating the expressions](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1179235402134). In Your case you can have some table with the formulas, for example

```
create table FORMULA
(
  ID         INTEGER not null,
  EXPRESSION VARCHAR2(4000)
);
alter table FORMULA
  add constraint PK_FORMULA_ID primary key (ID);
```

Populate some data here.

```
insert into formula (ID, EXPRESSION)
values (1, '1 * (12.1 * POWER(in_variable,2.06))');
commit;
```

Create the package from the above link.

```
create or replace package eval is

   function do_it(p_function in varchar2, p_var in number) return number;

end eval;
/
create or replace package body eval is

   g_theCursor integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;

   function do_it(p_function in varchar2, p_var in number) return number is
      l_rowsprocessed number default 0;
      l_retval number;
   begin
      dbms_sql.parse(g_theCursor,
                     'begin :ret_val := ' ||
                      replace(p_function, 'in_variable', ':in_variable') ||
                      '; end;', dbms_sql.native);

      dbms_sql.bind_variable(g_theCursor, ':ret_val', l_retval);
      begin
         dbms_sql.bind_variable(g_theCursor, ':in_variable', p_var);
      exception
         when others then
            if (sqlcode = -1006) then
               null;
            else
               raise;
            end if;
      end;
      l_rowsprocessed := dbms_sql.execute(g_theCursor);
      dbms_sql.variable_value(g_theCursor, ':ret_val', l_retval);

      return l_retval;
   end do_it;

end eval;
/
```

And voila!

```
declare
   in_variable int := 5;
begin
   for F in (select * from formula) loop
      dbms_output.put_line(eval.do_it('1 * (12.1 * POWER(in_variable,2.06))', in_variable));
   end loop;
end;
```

We will get the result.

```
333.168228204034354868248961030690574583
```

I don't know Your exact requirment, so I didn't have answers to the following questions do You need attributes to Your expressions? or do You need the dynamic substition? and etc. But still I Hope this will help You, to have some starting point.